# Why does the log loss function return undefined when the prediction has 1 or 0?

Tags: python, r, neural-network, deep-learning, evaluation

Below is the R code I used to calculate log loss:

```
LogLoss <- function(pred, res){
    (-1/length(pred)) * sum (res * log(pred) + (1-res)*log(1-pred)) }
```

However, if the prediction list contains 0 or 1, the corresponding log loss would return Infinity or NaN respectively.

```
LogLoss(c(0.9,0,0.2), c(1,1,1))
```

> [1] NaN

```
LogLoss(c(0.9,1,0.2), c(1,1,1))
```

> [1] Inf

I don't quite understand why this is the case, won't this make it impossible to calculate log loss if the result contains a 0 or 1?

Comment: I get the reverse for `NaN` and `Inf`, don't think that changes your overall question. Odd, I don't know why `0*log(0)` is `NaN`, I would expect it to be 0 ...

Comment: Brother could you please tell what  c in `c(0.9, 0, 0.9)` does?

Comment: @r2evans I think log(0) is infinity and 0*infinity is also infinity.

Comment: `log(0)` is technically undefined, so that makes more sense to me. Ref: https://www.rapidtables.com/math/algebra/ln/Ln_of_0.html. As for the `c` in `c(0.9, 0, 0.9)`, it's a fundamental function in R for building/concatenating vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is we are dealing with logarithm of 0.

When we use logloss, if the prediction is 0 or 1, we usually use [minmax rule](http://wiki.fast.ai/index.php/Log_Loss) to perturb it away from 0 and 1.

For example,

```
> pred = max(min(c(0.9,0,0.2), 1-10^-15), 10^-15)
> LogLoss(pred, c(1,1,1))
[1] 103.6163
```

Remark:

I experimented and obtained the result that is opposite as yours. log(0) = -Inf and 0*log(0) = NaN (0 times infinity is NaN)